# Asking help to write DAX Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I wanted to get percentage of student vs median of all.

| Student Name | Head to Toe |
| --- | --- |
| Student 1 | 2 |
| Student 2 | 3 |
| Student 3 | 5 |
| Student 4 | 6 |

The median for all is 4

I wanted to create a measure that shows the % of Number of Skills done vs the median while all the filters of student name is applied as well.

This is my Measure so far but it doesnt seem to work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aAMi.png)

```
%HeadtoToe = 
VAR HTCohort= SUM(Assessment_Skills[Head_To_Toe])
VAR HTStudent = MEDIAN(Assessment_Skills[Head_To_Toe])
VAR RESULT = DIVIDE(HTCohort,HTStudent)
RETURN RESULT
```

Thanks for any help I could get.

I tried writing my own dax measure but it seemed to be not working as it shows different value on my visualization card.

Answer (score 0):

```
Skills Done = SUM('Student Scores'[Head to Toe])
Median All = MEDIANX(ALL('Student Scores'),[Head to Toe])
%HeadToToe = DIVIDE ([Skills Done],[Median All],BLANK())
```

What are the "correct" answers given your dataset?